# Set TextBox dimensions to fit content in print style/css

Tags: html, css

I am working on a print style sheet and I would like the text in my text boxes to be fully visible when the content on the screen is printed. Currently I have set the width to 100% so that it fills the available space but the text is still being cut off.

I need for the text box to grow in height as well as width, for the content to wrap and not to have it's content cut off.

I don't even know if what I want is possible but I figured I'd ask since I'm not finding anything very useful on the web.

Here is my current print style:

```
input[disabled~='disabled'],
input[readonly~='readonly'],
textarea[disabled~='disabled'],
textarea[readonly~='readonly'],
input[type="text"], textarea
{
    width: 100%;
    display:block;
    overflow:visible;
    padding:2px;

    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #000000;
    border:none;
}
```

Thank you